# Infopath validation issue

Tags: validation, sharepoint-2013, infopath

I experienced the following validation error today using my Infopath form via a SharePoint 2013 list:

'The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values). Field or group: my:group1 Error: Cannot be blank
Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.'

I have no idea where to locate this 'group1' because I am pretty sure it doesn't exist!

I have gone through all the fields - never experienced this before.  I did look over the web and found someone mentioning lookup tables via another list - but I do not have any look up tables.

Any suggestions greatly received.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It is one of two things.

1. You have a required field and are using a rule to hide the section. Infopath is not intelligent enough to realize the rule should not error on the field that is hidden. The way to fix this is to remove the required rule and then instead add a validation rule on the field that you are trying to hide. For example if "Field 1" is Yes and Field 2 (the hidden one) is blank, then show error message.
2. The second one is a bug that occurs after changing a fields type. You may need to delete the field Group 1 and then recreate it.